# Angular 4 - How to give project level dependecy

Tags: angular, typescript, setup-project

I have couple of projects independent to each other. However I am planning to place common functionalities like graphs, data processing etc., inside a common project and give dependency on the other projects. However I think it will be good idea to have them as independent codebase so only the required components will be deployed.

The following is the structure I am hoping I can achieve.

```
project1
    - app
       - src

project2
    - app
       - src

project-common
    - app
       - src
```

project1 and project2 are independent to each other but they should use project-common components or modules.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should just make the common stuff a lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the exact use case for Nx,

This CLI tool will give you the utility to generate module libs which are independent apps. Adding new angular module lib is just as easy as running,

```
ng g lib myAwesomeKit --ngmodule --export
```

and it will create a new angular module lib with a module class. And then in your angular apps import your module and make use of the components. Checkout https://nrwl.io/nx for more.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Scaffolding is not an alternative to coding. The implication that the framework is so complex that you cannot write the code yourself, or give an answer to an architectural question, is just ridiculous. Thumbs way down